# How to center tempAlert by Travis J

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code:

How can I center the message horizontally?

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-    color:white;");
el.innerHTML = msg;
setTimeout(function(){
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
},duration);
document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: change the value for `left` in the style?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to center by changing the following line:

```
    el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:white;");
```

Basically, get rid of the "left:20%" and add a "text-align:center" and "width:100%".

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `margin: auto` property to it, and it should center it according to whatever div you're in. your function would look like:

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
     var el = document.createElement("div");
     // center, and apply an element width of 0
     el.setAttribute("style", "margin: auto;width: 0;");
     el.innerHTML = msg;
     setTimeout(function(){
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     },duration);
     document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

nice reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8tdLegkL/)